# How do I use the touch in Flash AIR and AS3?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I am making a game which is simple to control, I have made it in AS2 and there I use

```
if (Key.isDown(1)) {
    yspeed -= power*thrust;
}
```

so when user is holding the mouse click down the hero moves up, but in AS3 I can't seem to figure it out, I want to make the same game for android and iPhone so I made a new file as Android AIR and now I am programming in AS3 but I can't seem to find out how to do this, I've tried with

```
block.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doSomething);
function doSomething(event:MouseEvent):void{
trace("Box has been clicked");
}
```

but when I go to test, and I turn on the "touch layer" noting happens, but when I turn it off and click on *block* is traces "Box has been clicked"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you set the input mode? I think this is the problem.

You can check the reference here (examples provided): http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1ca064e08d7aa93023c59dfc1257b16a3d6-7ffe.html

Comment: It's nice to post out how, just to have a valid answer others can see :)

Comment: I've used 2 even listeners, for mouse up and down, so when it's up a variable gets value TRUE and vice versa, and in onEnterFrame function I have if (variable==tru) { do smth } :)